# After declaring a __m256 fail to access its members

Tags: c++, intrinsics, icc

When i tried to compile with icpc it shows "expression must have class type." Got confused about this. Please help.

```
int main()
{
    __m256d temp;
    temp.m256d_f64[0] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler/platform ?

Comment: @HannesHauptmann Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Intel c++

Comment: As far as I know, you cant access the values directly like in your code. Try using a function which does that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this problem on my end. In the immintrin.h shipped with Intel Compiler, we have the following definition for __m256d:

```
typedef struct _MMINTRIN_TYPE(32) __m256d {
    double m256d_f64[4];
} __m256d;
```

In the above definition, the struct name and alias are same which is confusing the current compiler. Intel Compiler doesn't seem to recognize the typedef name as a class which can proved with a smaller testcase:

```
$ cat test1.cc
typedef struct __m256d {
    double m256d_f64[4];
} m256d;

int main()
{
    __m256d temp;
    temp.m256d_f64[0] = 1;
    return 0;
}
$ icpc test1.cc –c
```

When I change the typedef and instantiate temp as shown below (use the typedefed name instead of struct name), ICC fails but GCC works:

```
$ cat test1.cc
typedef struct m256d {
    double m256d_f64[4];
} __m256d;

int main()
{
    __m256d temp;
    temp.m256d_f64[0] = 1;
    return 0;
}
$ icpc test1.cc -c
test1.cc(8): error: expression must have class type
      temp.m256d_f64[0] = 1;
      ^

compilation aborted for test1.cc (code 2)
$ g++ test1.cc -c
```

I have reported this issue to compiler engineering team at Intel.